# How to pass data to following rest api class using Postman?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, postman

Basically I am not understanding that how to send data rest-api class using Postman ?
When I use Postman to run rest-api to save record it gives me errors like application json format not supported..

I have following class to represent Many to Many relation

```
package com.ps.usercourse;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.ps.course.Course;
import com.ps.user.User;

@Entity
public class UserCourse implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 46419863112677606L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserCourseId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("emailId")
    @JsonBackReference
    User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("courseId")
    @JsonBackReference
    Course course;

    Boolean isActive = true;

    public UserCourse() {
    }

    public UserCourse(User user, Course course, Boolean isActive) {
        this.user = user;
        this.course = course;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public UserCourse(UserCourseId id, User user, Course course, Boolean isActive) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
        this.course = course;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public UserCourseId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UserCourseId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public Boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) 
            return false;

        UserCourse that = (UserCourse) o;
        return Objects.equals(user, that.user) && 
               Objects.equals(course, that.course);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(user, course);
    }
}
```

---

This is rest api that I am trying to call through Postman

```
@RequestMapping(value="/UserCourse",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public UserCourse addUser(@RequestBody UserCourse userCourse, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    {
        return userCourseService.save(userCourse);
    }
```

Comment: did you set Content-Type header as application/json ?

Comment: can you share your json which you tried with Postman?

Comment: and also share your User and Course class